# htaccess rewrite problems page.html?{rewrite} --> page.html

Tags: .htaccess

I have problem with htaccess rewrite rule.

I have page for example:

```
www.oldpage.com/55,city.html?partner_id=7
www.oldpage.com/subpage/158,blog.html?partner_id=8
```

And I want to rewrite this page on:

```
www.newpage.com/55,city.html
www.newpage.com/subpage/158,blog.html
```

It is possible? Maybe I must redirect links with .html?partner_id on normal .html, after on newpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding in .htaccess for newpage.com this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^partner_id=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the QSD flag (query string discard)

```
 RewriteRule .* ww.newpage.com/$1 [NC,QSD]
```

Comment: QSD is available with apache 2.4 and above

Comment: so what I can do when I don't have apache 2.4? because it don't work

Comment: You can try  to add another query_string : RewriteRule .* ww.newpage.com/$1?whatever [NC] . but i'm out of idea